# Extracting chars from inside '(' and ')' from char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, char, extract

I am stuck on this problem:
A user writes a math expression and the program need to extract from it all subexpressions that are inside ( ) ex. (x+2) or (x+(y-2)).

---

For example, if the user enters 2-(5+(x-6)-(y+9)), the program should return (x-6), (y+9), (5+(x-6)-(y+9))

This is what I've tried to do.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a[100];
    int i=0,t,j=0;
    printf("enter math expression:\n");
    while( (a[i++]=getchar()) != '\n' && i < 100);
    a[i] = '\0';

  for (i=0; a[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]=='(')
        {   printf("found (\n");
            j++;
              while (a[i] !=')')
                printf("%c",a[i++]);

                printf("%c",a[i]);
```

Comment: Great. Just ask a question if you are stuck. Do not forget to provide a **specific** problem description along with a [mcve]. You also might want to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: You're incrementing `i` inside the `while` loop. So your program will jump over any other, if existing, `(` before finding the first `)` and cannot go back. Just something to think about.

Comment: @Mihai Will it be possible somehow to skip some `)` ? I mean not to stop printing chars on first occurrence of `)`, but for example on second one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let, `s` be a cstring in this context.

Since in valid mathematical expression parenthesis are balanced, we can observe that,

2. s+1 is balanced if s[0] is not '('
3. if s[0] is '(' then we are at the start of a parenthesis'ed expression.

At the case of #1 we do not care about the first character. So, we can set s = s+1 and start over again.
At the case of #2 we have to find the matched end for the first character. So, we divide it in two part. The matched expression and the tail. Both are valid expression. So, we start with them over again.

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "2-(5+(x-6)-(y+9))";// s have to be modifiable.

    extractAndPrint(s, 0); // we are at start and 0 indicates balanced

    return 0;
}
```

Now,

```
void extractAndPrint(char *s, int found)
{
    if(s[0] == 0) return;//no more honey
    if(!found){ //so far balanced
        if(s[0] == '(') extractAndPrint(s+1, 1);// case 2
        else extractAndPrint(s+1, 0); //this is the case 1
    } else {//start of a expression
        char *t;
        //separates the end of current expression 
        //and the remaining part.
        mark_end(s, 0, &t);
        printf("(%s)\n", s);
        extractAndPrint(s, 0);//potentially contain more expression
        extractAndPrint(t, 0);//check past the previous exp
    }
}
```

I liked recursion here too. It takes less thinking for me. Can be implemented in more elegant way.

```
void mark_end(char *s, int c, char **t)
{
    if(c == 0){
        if(s[0] == ')'){
            *t = s+1;
            *s = '\0';
        } else if(s[0] == '('){
            mark_end(s+1, c+1, t);
        } else {
            mark_end(s+1, c, t);
        }
    } else {
        if(s[0] == ')'){
            mark_end(s+1, c-1, t);
        } else if(s[0] == '('){
            mark_end(s+1, c+1, t);
        } else {
            mark_end(s+1, c, t);
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
(5+(x-6)-(y+9))
(x-6)
(y+9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are dealing with nested expressions, you need to keep a **stack** around in order to match parentheses. Ideally inside the loop you should:

1. Whenever found a '(', push position within the string into the stack
2. When a ')' is found, then pop from the stack the position of the matching '('. You have start-end indexes for your expression.
3. Continue until string is finished

Example `(x + (y+2))`:

```
i == 0 -> '(' -> s.push(0);
i == 1 -> 'x' 
i == 2 -> '+'
i == 3 -> '(' -> s.push(3);
i == 4 -> 'y'
i == 5 -> '+'
i == 6 -> '2'
i == 7 -> ')' -> s.pop() [3, 7] contains '(y + 2)'
i == 8 -> ')' -> s.pop() [0, 8] contains '(x + (y+2))'
```

Comment: Thanks for response,  but how about situation like `(x+(y-2))`
First `(` will match first `)` and this is wrong

Comment: I added an example above in my answer

Comment: Thank you very much. `Push` and `pop` is something new for me, going to google it further.

Comment: Well, there are 2 main functionality of a Stack -> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Structures/Stacks_and_Queues

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use state machine, in your case this state machine should be suitable :[image]

so your main will be a kind of a switch case, take care of writing your pop and push fuctions and represent your heap with a good structure

Answer (score 0):

You should use recursion to parse the string as a tree of parenthesis. Here is an example showing how to do it :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_DATA 100

int mathexp(const char *exp, int start, int end)
{
  int i = start;
  while(i < (start + end) && exp[i] != ')') {
    if(exp[i] == '(') {
      i = mathexp(exp, i + 1, end) + 1;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
  char subexp[i - start];
  memcpy(subexp, &exp[start], i - start);
  subexp[i - start] = '\0';
  printf("%s\n", subexp);
  return i;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  char input[MAX_DATA];
  printf("Enter a math expression: ");
  fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
  input[strcspn(input, "\r\n")] = '\0'; // remove trailing \r\n
  mathexp(input, 0, strlen(input));
  return 0;
}
```

and when you test it, you have :

```
Enter a math expression: 2-(5+(x-6)-(y+9))
x-6
y+9
5+(x-6)-(y+9)
2-(5+(x-6)-(y+9))
```